# How can I boot from USB with an Asus M2400N laptop?

Tags: boot, laptop, usb, asus-laptop

I own [this](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/laptops/43394/asus-m2400n) wonderful Asus M2400N laptop from 2003, which is still performing great, and I'm desperately trying to boot from a USB key drive (or SD Card via an PCMCIA card reader). [Hardware info here](http://people.easter-eggs.org/~valos/Asus_M2400N/Asus_M2400N.html).

Neither is working.

The bios states it can boot from HDD, CDROM and also a mysterious "removable device", which I thought was USB. The bios vesion is 0208 from American Megatrends.

I also tried [Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/full.html) - to no avail - no inserted USB key drive is found. Also Super Grub Disk 1 did not work.

I have to boot from USB, CDROM doesn't help me due to file system limitations (frankly, I want to boot to Chrome OS).

Can anybody help me out here? Has anyone managed to boot from USB with that gear?
It would be really appreciated since I'm trying and researching since an eternity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a bootable flash disk, If you want to boot linux you should create with unetbootin. Or you can use windows to boot. [how to boot windows from flash drive](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, of course I have bootable images for USB available. Both my USB key drive and my sd card are booting fine on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It is not possible to boot from any USB flash disk drive with this laptop. Instead, I used an external USB HDD which then worked.

Only thing I had to do is to transfer the partitions from the USB key drive to the external HDD via the unix dd - tools.

(Also, it is possible to directly write an USB image file (*.img) to the external HDD via dd if=yourimage.img of=/dev/yourdisk).